# Automated server side rebuild of Domino applications

Tags: ibm-domino

We have a strange problem where XPages stop working (like they would not exist) almost every day. The solution is the rebuild the app with Domino Designer. I'm quite tired of doing that many times a week.

I have not found a solution and I'm thinking about automaticaly rebuilding the applications in server side every day. So far I haven't figured out how to do that. Is it possible and how?

*Domino 9.0.1FP6 on Windows 64bit*

**Update:**

Found this "command line building":

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRGU_9.0.1/user/wpd_srcctrl_headless_command_line.html

It's close but looks like it will create a new NSF from source files:

> file name - A string value containing the name of the NSF/NTF to be
>   created.

I need to rebuild an existing NSF file.

Comment: Downvoters, as always please comment. I will then try to improve the question based on feedback. Thanks.

I haven't tried any solution because I haven't found any.

Comment: OK, there is also one voting that this question should be closed as unclear. How about I make it clearer, wouldn't that be better? Just tell me what is unclear because it seems crystal clear to me. Thanks.

Comment: I may have found a fix, it has worked now for 2 days. My Designer is FP10 and I was using Java compiler level 1.6 to match the server version. But maybe that was not enough. I installed JRE1.6 and am using that now for building.

Answer (score 1):

I personally would rather go for fixing the CAUSE then working around the problem. 
If this happens every day, then it is most probably the Designer- Task that breaks your app. Either disable Designer- Task in ServertasksAt1- Line of notes.ini (no one really needs that on an automated basis as it causes more problem than it solves) or fix the template by recompiling it in designer.

Just enter

```
set config ServerTasksAt1=Catalog
```

to your server console and disable the designer task that usually is enabled there (Default: ServerTasksAt1=Catalog,Designer)

Comment: I fully agree. This is tricky case because it's a corporate environment where I don't have admin access and I'm not able to reach Domino admins. But if I have clear instructions I _may be_ able to push them thru via service desk.

These NSFs do not inherit from template. Do you think Designer task could still somehow cause problems?